# Finding an object in NSSet of different objects

Tags: objective-c, search, nsset

I have a `NSSet` that contains 3 different types of objects (`FacebookGroup`, `Individual` and `NSMutableDictionary`)

`FacebookGroup` and `Individual` are subclasses of `NSManagedObject`

Now I want to try to find an object matching key `contactInfo` so I do like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *contactDict = [[self.contacts filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactInfo == %@", contactInfo]] anyObject];

if (contactDict) // the object is found
```

But `FacebookGroup`s does not have the key `contactInfo` so an exception is throwed. I was hoping that instead an exception being throwed `contactDict` would be `nil`.

How can I search a `NSSet` of different objects without an exception being throwed?

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity FacebookGroup is not key value coding-compliant for the key "contactInfo".'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you're searching for is a *NSMutableDictionary*, that's the way of recognizing it from other objects, sending a *isKindOfClass* message. So you should create a predicate that evaluates every object:

```
NSPredicate* predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass: [NSMutableDictionary class]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create your predicate using `+ (NSPredicate *)predicateWithBlock:(BOOL (^)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings))block` then you can perform a check in the block to ensure that the `evaluatedObject` has the key and then perform the appropriate check.